# c# forms outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

When I want to receive 3 values from the database.

```
16.5
15.5
15.5
```

With this code:

```
public static double calculateTotalPrice(int reserveringId)
{
    double total=0;
    int i = 0;

    SqlCommand comm =  sqlCrud.returnSqlCommand("select g.prijs from gerechten g inner join besteld b on b.gerechtId=g.gerechtId where b.reserveringId='"+reserveringId+"'");

    SqlDataReader dt = comm.ExecuteReader();

    if (dt.HasRows)
    {
        while (dt.Read())
        {
            total += dt.GetDouble(i);
            i++;
        }
    }

    return total;
}
```

It's telling me:

> Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Exactly what the error message says.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use an index that you should increment in order you read the values that the query returns. Actually, this query returns the values stored in the column `prijs` of table called `gerechten`. Hence, it's row has one value in the position with index 0.

```
public static double calculateTotalPrice(int reserveringId)
{
    double total=0;
    SqlCommand comm =  sqlCrud.returnSqlCommand("select g.prijs from gerechten g inner join besteld b on b.gerechtId=g.gerechtId where b.reserveringId='"+reserveringId+"'");
    SqlDataReader dt = comm.ExecuteReader();
    if (dt.HasRows)
    {
        while (dt.Read())
        {
            total += dt.GetDouble(0);
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

As a side note, I would suggest you prefer to write parameterized sql queries and not use string concatenation to build your query. The latter approach is open to one of the most common security holes, *sql injection*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works! But why does the query return 1 number. When I exec this in mssql it gives me 3? And normally I use parameterized queries but I wanted to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: The query will return the values of  `prijs`, whose `reserveringId` matches the given one.  These values may be 3 or more,  but each row in the set that the query returns would have one value, this of `prijs`. Then using a sql data reader you read these values one at a time and add them to the total.